# Euclidean Division

Tags: math-mode

I'm a learning Latex and i'm struggling at typing this euclidean division.
Can someone write me the correct algorithme please?
Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBYwb.png)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show what you've got so far (minimal, compilable code example; MWE).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want? As small braces look ugly, I replace them with brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, array, boldline}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\qquad}*{4}{r@{}}!{\enspace} V{2.5}l@{\qquad}c}
    A & X³ & {} +3X² & {} + 2X & {}+1 & X² + 1 & B \\
    \clineB{6-7}{2.5}
    Q₁B & X³ & & {}+ X & \\
    \cline{1-5}
    A-Q₁B & & 3X² & {} + X & {} + 1 & \underbracket[0.6pt][3pt]{\,X\,}_{\textstyle Q₁} + \underbracket[0.6pt][3pt]{\,3\,}_{\textstyle Q₂} & Q \\
    Q₂B & & 3X² & & {} + 3 \\
    \cline{1-5}
    R & & & X & {}-2
  \end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]